# Open questions in mesh generation

Tags: computational-geometry

A mesh is a discretization of a geometric domain. An unstructured mesh is typically a triangulation. Unstructured meshes are catching up especially in the academic community. 
I'm looking for  open questions in 2D mesh generation, specifically outstanding theoretical problems for refinements of triangles: for example, show that angles stay bounded away from zero in sucessive iterations of division methods.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/>http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d34a8238de.jpg border=0 alt="5th iteration equilateral triangle trisection">

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Meshing Research Corner](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/sowen/mesh.html) and [International Meshing Roundtable](http://www.imr.sandia.gov/).